# Trying to add up values into a matrix

Tags: matrix, evaluation, summation, procedural-programming

first post here.

I'm currently completely stuck and frustrated with mathematica. In retrospective, it might had been a mistake to use it for this, I'm actually considering to somehow export the results I have so far into python.
Disregarding that: What I have right now are two nested lists/matrices, one of which is empty and is supposed to be filled by the nested list. The nested list is organized in such a way that each line has a value, and 2 positional values, to insert into the matrix.
I've been trying to use while loops, for loops etc. and everytime it just returns an unchanged empty matrix to me.

Some "pseudo-code" I've been actually using:

```
Test1 = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}}
FinTest1 = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}]
i = 1;
While[i < 4, Print[i];
  j = 1;
  While[j < 4,
   n = 1;
   While[n < 4,
    If[i === Test1[[n, 3]] And j === Test1[[n, 2]],
     FinTest1[[i, j]] = FinTest1[[i, j]] + Test1[[n, 1]]];
    n++];
   j++];
  m++];
MatrixForm[FinTest1]
```

This one is a heavily simplified version of what I am currently doing (Mine has around a million of data and the matrix is around 50 times larger). As you might see, at least that's something I expected to get, is a matrix in the form of:

```
{{4,0,0},{0,0,2},{0,0,0}}
```

Instead I get the empty matrix back, as if nothing happened with it. I've also noticed that the iterables stay the same within each loop, meaning i is always 1 inside the inner-most While loop, even though it should iterate.

Mind you, these are just my calculations, that's all I've been using Mathematica for so far. It's the first time I use some kind of "proper code" in this. But it turns out that somehow it treats values inside the loops differently from normally. Is there a way to circumvent that?

Comment: To start with, your syntax for And is wrong.

Comment: I'm making some assumptions, but maybe you're trying to do something like this: `SparseArray[Rule[{#1, #2}, #3] & @@@ Test1, {3, 3}]`

Comment: @lericr It's mostly experimental. Though it didn't seem to have an issue with it. Replace seems to be a wonderful function. Though now I'm having a problem with drawing a matrixplot/arrayplot. All I get is "Argument {Matrix} at position 1 is not a list of lists". Even though it is... Does Wolfram have a maximum matrix size which it is willing to plot? (360x180)

Comment: that sounds like a new question. but you should trust the error message and try to fix that first.

Comment: @lericr Managed to find the mistake. Replace seems to cause the problem by turning the matrix into a ragged list (somehow a few elements simply seem to disappear). SpraseArray on the other hand seems to have a problem with decimal values (around 10^-4)

Comment: all of those assumptions seem unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using [`While`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/While), it is simpler to process the `Test1` variable as follows:

```
Test1 = {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 1}};
FinTest1 = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];

Replace[Test1, {i_, j_, k_} :> AddTo[FinTest1[[j,k]], i], {1}];
FinTest1
```

> {{4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}

It is also possible to modify [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) options to do this as well, e.g.:

```
old = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries"];
SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> "TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total];
```

Then, using [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray):

```
SparseArray[Replace[Test1, {i_, j_, k_} :> {j, k} -> i, {1}]] //Normal
```

> {{4, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 2}}

Finally, reset the [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray) options:

```
SetSystemOptions[old];
```

Comment: Thanks. It actually calculated it extremely fast, but there seems to be a problem with it removing some elements from the matrix, or at least making wolfram think that it's a ragged list which cannot be converted into an array nor matrix.
SparseArray causes problems with the following error message:
`The left-hand side of {89,0}->0.000109064 in {{89, -29} (shortened)
0.0000853162, {90, 7} -> 0.0000215934} is not a position or a pattern \
that will match the position of an element in an array with depth`

Comment: Right, this is for the 360x180 matrix I'm using. I've checked the dimensions of the inputs, and they're correct, 360 180.

Comment: Mathematica starts indexing matrices with 1, not 0. `j` and `k` must be positive integers.

Comment: Oh right. Thanks